# Set serial port pin high using python

Tags: python, serial-port

Is it possible to set one pin of the serial port continuously high using python (or C)?
If yes, how?

Comment: Which API are you using to access the serial port?

Answer (score 18):

Using the pyserial methods `setRTS(level=True)` and `setDTR(level=True)` you can control the RTS and DTR lines at will. For instance, the following code will toggle the RTS pin of the first serial port. (See the pyserial documentation for the details).

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(0)
ser.setRTS(False)
time.sleep(0.5)
ser.setRTS(True)
time.sleep(0.5)
ser.setRTS(False)
```

Comment: ser = serial.Serial('COM1',9600)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is **possible** using [**pySerial**](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

If you open the port, the Tx line should go to the voltage high state, and if you never send data it should stay in that state (see [here](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/RS-232_specs.html#bits)).  I've never actually tried this though.  You might find you need to enable one of the control lines instead, like CTR.

As for software, [TheMachineCharmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438848/set-serial-port-pin-high-using-python/2438871#2438871)'s suggestion of pySerial is the most platform independent way of doing it.  If you're on Windows, the Win32 API calls are summarized [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx).  Look for `CreateFile` and (if you need to set control lines) `GetCommState` and `SetCommState`.  Note that the filename you pass to `CreateFile` should look like `"\\\\.\\COM1"`.  The .NET way of doing is is summarized [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.aspx).  You'll need to construct a `SerialPort` object, then access its properties to set control lines.