# PWM signal out of serial port with linux

Tags: c++, python, embedded

How to to send out a pwm signal from the serial port with linux? (With python or c++)

I want to connect a motor directly to change the speed rotation.

Comment: You should not connect anything beyond receiver chips to a serial port - they are not designed to be/replace a power source

Comment: Nothing localized about the question.  The possibility of force-fitting what you have to a problem you need to solve in a good-enough manner is a common one.

Comment: For some purposes, it may be in enough to use the logic level serial out as a PWM signal, by repeatedly transmitting a character and using the number of bits that are on/off in the character to set the duty cycle.  There would of course be severe drawbacks, such as not being able to go to 100% duty cycle and having relatively course resolution.  Using the serial channel to command an external device doing the PWM generation of course eliminates that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is possibly ill-advised unless you really know what you are doing with the interfacing.  Any signal driven from those pins if used at all should only supply signal level drive - you would have to use this to control a motor *controller* or amplifier  actual motor drive, do not connect a motor directly.  Moreover the signals out of a serial port swing -ve and +ve rather than zero/+ve.

One possibility is to use the DTR signal since that can normally be independently controlled (as described in [Set serial port pin high using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438848/set-serial-port-pin-high-using-python) for example), however through software you may not get the frequency or precision required to control a motor accurately or efficiently, and if the software fails you could leave the motor running at full-speed - so some care is required.

A better solution is to get a dedicated digital and/or PWM I/O card or USB device, or even a purpose build motor controller interface.  Industrial computer suppliers such as Advantech will have something suitable, and at lower cost perhaps, any number of robotics hobby suppliers.

Comment: Thank you, I will try with DTR signal (I don't need high precision).

Comment: @o1863176:  You say that, but your motor might go wildly out of control if the controlling process is starved of CPU time due to other processes, leaving the motor either fully on or fully off for non-deterministic lengths of time.  Normally a hardware generated PWM and/or and RTOS would be appropriate.  There are ways of mitigating timing jitter in Linux which might produce acceptable results. See [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-real-time-linux/index.html) and [this](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/Linux-For-Devices-Articles/Seven-realtime-Linux-approaches-Part-C/)

Comment: I realised that the pwm frequency I need for the motor can't be managed by a not realtime operating system, then I have to use something like arduino or other, or manual controller. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

doubt you can do this you are using a uart interface...just get an arduino or someat and send serial commands to the arduino (serial pins) which then puts the correct pwm signal out its pins ... probably 5 lines of arduino code and another 5 of python code ...

all that said you may be able to find some very difficult and hacky way to output a PWM signal over serial ... but you need to think about if thats really appropriate ...

Comment: I would avoid to use arduino or another external circuit. If I can't do this I will use a manual controller. Thanks.

Comment: just curious? why? arduino is great imho ... so easy to do embedded stuff and this seems like a good time to get your hands wet with IC's and arduino is a great entry level one with easy learning curve... that said there could be a real reason you dont want to...

Comment: I use already Arduino, but in this case i don't like the arduino solution, there aren't technical motivations :)

Comment: ok :) ... just makin sure you weren't discounting it entirely :P