# python serial.Serial is only working in the debugger

Tags: python, serial-port, ipython

I'm trying to use the python serial library to send a voltage command between two computers. I'm using the USB ports on the two computers to do this, connected via a natational instruments A/D board. I have been able to successfully do this using the following code:

```
portObj = serial.Serial(serialPortName)

if direction == 'Off': #direction is an input provided by the user that determines whether to turn on or off the voltage command
     portObj.setRTS(True) #turns OFF ttl
     print('TTL set to OFF')

elif direction == 'On':
     portObj.setRTS(False) #turns ON ttl
     print('TTL set to ON')
```

Everything works as expected when I run the code line by line in the console: the voltage command flips between ON and OFF states depending on the value of `direction`. However, when I try to put the code into a method and call it dynamically based on user input, it stops working.

Some further details: I can get the code to work in the method if I put a breakpoint in and run the line that says `portObj = serial.Serial(serialPortName)` manually. Also, after I've run things through the debugger once, the method works as expected on all future calls until I close the console.

I'm using Spyder/IPython to run my code.

Comment: Sounds like a possible race condition / time needed for changes to propagate: e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438848/set-serial-port-pin-high-using-python) `time.sleep` is used. Also note that `setRTS` is [deprecated](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.setRTS) and you should assign to `rts` property directly instead.